# polar curves integration with $(dx)^2$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

> Find the area which lies between the x-axis and the curve $x = sin(t)$, $y = sin(t)cos(t)$, where $0 \le t \le \pi/2$

I was able to sketch a graph in the x-y coordinate plane by making a table of $t$, $x$, and $y$, and I know that the next step is to integrate, but I'm a little confused as to how to go about it.

Would it be $\int_{t_0}^{t_1} y(t) dx = \int_{0}^{\pi/2} {\sin(t) \cos(t)} dx$, where $dx = \cos(t) dt$? I think that should be right enough, but my friend says this could also work: $\int_{x_0}^{x_1} y dx$, where $y = x dx$ and so it'd be $\int_{0}^{1} x d^2x$—but is the latter a valid integral? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

You must be able to visualize what the expression means.

Basically, if you add up the area of the infinitesimal rectangles, it gives you the Area.

[image]

Area of one such rectangle is $dA=y\left(x\right)dx$. Hence the integral must always be $A=\int_{ }^{ }dA=\int_{ }^{ }y\left(x\right)dx$.

Rest is all mathematical manipulation. If you wish to solve this in terms of $t$, then convert both $x$ and $y$ in terms of $t$. If you wish to do it in terms of $x$, write $y$ in terms of $x$.

In the $t$ world,

$$dx=\cos\left(t\right)dt$$
$$y=\sin\left(t\right)\cos\left(t\right)$$
$$A=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin\left(t\right)\cos^{2}\left(t\right)dt=\frac13$$

In the $x$ world,

$$y=\sin\left(t\right)\cos\left(t\right)=x\left(\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\right)$$
$$A=\int_{0}^{1}x\sqrt{1-x^{2}}dx=\frac13$$

Now, the thing about $(dx)^2$ is just some calculation mistake. In that way, it can be done as follows:

$$dx=\cos\left(t\right)dt$$
$$\cos\left(t\right)=\frac{dx}{dt}$$
$$y=\sin\left(t\right)\cos\left(t\right)=x\frac{dx}{dt}$$
$$A=\int_{ }^{ }x\cdot\frac{dx}{dt}\cdot dx$$

Again you need to change it either into $t$ world or into $x$ world. The results will be always the same. Just stick to basics. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the Cartesian form of the integral is $y=f(x),\,x\in[a,b]$. Let the parametrization $x=g(t)$ and $y=f(g(t)) = h(t)$ with $t\in[\alpha,\beta]$. It follows that $dx=g'(t)dt$ and

$$A=\int_{a=f(\alpha)}^{b=f(\beta)}f(x)\,dx=\int_{\alpha}^\beta h(t)g'(t)dt.$$

For your example, $g(t)=\sin(t)$ and $h(t)=\sin(t)\cos(t)$ with $t\in[0,\pi/2]$, so

$$A=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(t)\cos^2(t)\,dt\to\text{$u=\cos(t)$}\to\int_0^1u^2\,du=\frac13.$$

You could also subsitute $x(t)$ into $y(t)$, yielding $y=x\sqrt{1-x^2},\,$ $x\in[0,1]$ which when integrating yields the same answer of $1/3$.